# Delete values lower than cummax on multiple spark dataframe columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a data frame as shown below. The number of signals are more than 100, so there will be more than 100 columns in the data frame.

```
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|id |        date|signal01|signal02|signal03|......
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |3       |1       |
|050|2021-01-15  |null    |4       |2       |
|050|2021-02-02  |2       |3       |3       |

|051|2021-01-14  |1       |3       |0       |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |null    |null    |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |3       |2       |
|051|2021-02-03  |1       |3       |1       |

|052|2021-03-03  |1       |3       |0       |
|052|2021-03-05  |3       |3       |null    |
|052|2021-03-06  |2       |null    |2       |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |5       |5       |.......
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I have to find out cummax of each signal and then compare with respective signal columns and delete the signal records which are having value lower than cummax and null values.

step1. find cumulative max for each signal with respect to id column.

step2. delete the records which are having lower value than cummax for each signal.
[image]

step3. Take count of records which are having cummax less than signal value(excluded of null) for each signals with respect to id.

After the count the final output should be as shown below.

```
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|id |        date|signal01|signal02|signal03|.....
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |  3     | 1      | 
|050|2021-01-15  |null    |  null  | 2      | 
|050|2021-02-02  |2       |  3     | 3      | 
                                   |          
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |  3     | 0      | 
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |  null  | null   | 
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |  3     | 2      | 
|051|2021-02-03  |null    |  3     | null   | 
                                   |          
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |  3     | 0      | 
|052|2021-03-05  |3       |  3     | null   | 
|052|2021-03-06  |null    |  null  | 2      | 
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |  5     | 5      | ......
+----------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I have tried by using window function as below and it worked for almost all records.

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow) 
val signalList01 = ListBuffer[Column]() 
signalList01.append(col("id"), col("date")) 
for (column <- signalColumns) {         
// Applying the max non null aggregate function on each signal column           
signalList01 += (col(column), max(column).over(w).alias(column+"_cummax"))       } 
val cumMaxDf = df.select(signalList01: _*)
```

But I am getting error values as shown below for few records.
[image]

Is there any idea about how this error records in the cummax column? Any leads appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this part `I have tried by using window function but not able to proceed for all columns.`?

Comment: @Filip : I tried the below code part, but the logic is not complete and finding cummax only for one signal column. ```val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    df1.withColumn("signal01_cummax",
      max("signal01").over(w))
      .show(false)```

Comment: @Antony so your code above works but you need to apply it to all 100 columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Just giving out hints here (as you suggested) to help you unblock the situation, but --WARNING-- haven't tested the code !

1. the code you provided in the comments looks good. It'll get you your max column

   ```
   val nw_df = original_df.withColumn("singal01_cummax", sum(col("singal01")).over(windowCodedSO))
   ```
2. now, you need to be able to compare the two values in "singal01" and "singal01_cummax". A function like this, maybe:

   ```
   def takeOutRecordsLessThanCummax (signal:Int, singal_cummax: Int) : Any  = 
   { if (signal == null || signal < singal_cummax) null
   else   singal_cummax }
   ```
3. since we'll be applying it to columns, we'll wrap it up in a UDF

   ```
   val takeOutRecordsLessThanCummaxUDF : UserDefinedFunction = udf {
   (i:Int, j:Int) => takeOutRecordsLessThanCummax(i,j)
   }
   ```
4. and then, you can combine everything above so it can be applicable on your original dataframe. Something like this could work:

   ```
   val signal_cummax_suffix = "_cummax"

   val result = original_df.columns.foldLeft(original_df)(

   (dfac, colname) => dfac
   .withColumn(colname.concat(signal_cummax_suffix), 
    sum(col(colname)).over(windowCodedSO))
   .withColumn(colname.concat("output"), 
   takeOutRecordsLessThanCummaxUDF(col(colname), col(colname.concat(signal_cummax_suffix))))

    )
   ```

Comment: sum(col(colname)) will provide the cumulative sum, but i require cumulative max. I have tried with max instead of sum, but for few records i am not getting correct output, whereas for few i am getting correct output. I have updated the question with this..pls check